# Jquery for/while issue

Tags: jquery, for-loop, count, while-loop

http://jsfiddle.net/9nr6A/

As you can see in this fiddle I have a table with a lot of numbers, mostly these numbers are unitnumbers. For example:

```
         var numberofspear = $("#village_troup_list tbody tr:first")
        .find("td[data-unit='sword']").text();
         //This Equals 5
```

I've made my code to get each tr, and then get all the "numberofunits" in that tr. The code looks like this (to make it somewhat more simple, I'll only be using two columns in this example:

```
       var tds = $('#village_troup_list tbody tr td:nth-of-type(2)')
       .filter(function() {
       var val = $(this).text();
       alert(val);
       return val >= distancefrom && val <= distanceto;
       });
```

This gets all the trs I want, don't worry about this bit.

Then, I need to get all unitnumbers in every tr, so:

```
    tds.each(function(i, td) {
    var tr = $(td).parent();


    var numberofspear = parseInt($(tr).find("td[data-unit='spear']").text());
    var numberofsword = parseInt($(tr).find("td[data-unit='sword']").text());


    //So far so good, getting all units (two in this example)
    // Then I need to click every "selecteren" button if....

    var numberneeded = 1000;
    var totalnumberspearneeded = 10000;
    var totalnumberswordneeded = 11000;
    if (numberofspear >= numberneeded && numberofsword > numberneeded) function() {


    tr.find("input[value='Selecteren']:first").click();




    }



    });
```

After the "selecteren" button got clicked, my original static value changes to an editable input value, the html looks like this:

```
        <td data-unit="spear" class="tooltip">
        <input type="text" size="2" name="spear"/>
        </td>
```

Now the hard part: I want to change the input value of every editable td (every td that got clicked) to numberneeded for every unit (so all editable tds in the spear column, and all editable tds in the sword column) AS LONG AS the sum of all the changed values are smaller than or equal to "totalnumberofspearneeded" (for the spear column) and "totalnumberofswordneeded" (for the sword column), all the other ones need to be put to 0.

Now, two questions:

1) Changing the values isn't that simple:

```
   $(tr).find("input[name='spear']").val(numberneeded);
```

However, this finds ALL the inputs, even the ones that aren't activated, so then the above code gives undefined... How can I go around this?

2) AS LONG AS the sum of all the changed values are smaller than equal to "totalnumberofspearneeded" (for the spear column) and "totalnumberofswordneeded" (for the sword column), all the other ones need to be put to 0. -> How can i do this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if you meant to do this or not, but in JAVA you can use `>>`, but in JAVASCRIPT you cannot. If you wish to shift left and right, you must explicitly declare so.

Comment: I found the question to answer 1 myself. I put it in a var, and then if (var >== 0) function {}. I can't find any solution for question two though.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy No, that wasn't intentional :) Sorry.

Comment: Can you include your JavaScript in the fiddle? I'm not sure how to work out which inputs are "activated".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `<input>` tag is only added to the DOM after the button is clicked, you could start by finding all `<input>`s and setting them to zero:

```
$('#village_troup_list input').val(0);
```

You can then reset the desired fields to `numberneeded`, so long as the sum remains less than `totalnumberspearneeded`:

```
var counter = 0;
var numberneeded = 1000;
var totalnumberspearneeded = 10000;
$('#village_troup_list input[name="spear"]').each(function() {
    if (counter < totalnumberspearneeded) {
        // ensure that totalnumberspearneeded is not exceeded
        var inc = Math.min(numberneeded, totalnumberspearneeded - counter);
        // set the <input> value
        $(this).val(inc);
        // keep track of the total used so far
        counter += inc;
    } else {
        // totalnumberspearneeded has been reached, so break out of this
        // loop, leaving all the remaining inputs at zero
        return false;
    }
});
```

You could just duplicate this code for the swords, but it would be more sensible to refactor this code to remove the explicit reference to spears:

```
$.fn.fillToMax = function(preferredValue, maxTotal) {
    var counter = 0;
    this.each(function() {
        // same code as before, but with different variable names
    });
    return this;
}
```

This adds `fillToMax` as a method on the jQuery object, so you could then run it against both the spear and the sword selectors:

```
$('#village_troup_list input[name="spear"]').fillToMax(1000, 10000);
$('#village_troup_list input[name="sword"]').fillToMax(1000, 11000);
```